# IIS Application - content not returned

Tags: css, .net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have an IIS Website (asp.net mvc 5). Usual site with styles, scripts and images. the point of interest is this:

```
.bss-fullscreen {
z-index: 3;
display: block;
width: 24px;
height: 24px;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
background-image: url("/Content/SlideshowElements/arrows-alt_ffffff_64.png");
-webkit-background-size: contain;
background-size: contain;
position: absolute;
top: 5px;
left: 5px;
cursor: pointer;
opacity: .8;
}
```

And this image is contained in the folder and is returned successfully like 19 of 20, but occasionally the request to this image just hangs and is hanging until the browser tab actually crashes with out of memory error (Pending state in chrome). Any help is appreciated. Again, most of the time this image is returned successfully.
**Edit 1**
Actually, during this occasional "bad load" all the images get stuck in pending state

Comment: Have you ran procmon on the server and the client side while it is hanging to see what is running?  It could be something external to IIS or the website.  Does it happen on every computer that is trying to access the website?  Does it happen in different browsers?

Comment: happens on different browsers and different devices

Comment: Then I would try seeing what is running when it happens.  Use Procmon on the server and try to force it to happen.  Can you put in a breakpoint at the step after?  Then see if there is anything that looks out of sort?  Can you try a different picture file just to see if there is anything wrong with that file?  Does anything else access that same picture file at the same time?

Comment: The file is used exclusively by this site in this css, another interesting thing - it wasn't happening locally. I'll try procmon but everything else works as expected so not sure that it will reveal something